# Save string locally on device in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to save a small piece of data from a Xamarin Forms app locally on a device where it can be retrieved later.
I don't want to use SQL Lite, App.Config or save it as a file, it's basically just a string.
Is this possible, and if so does 
anyone have an example?

Comment: Did you take a look at Xam.Plugins.Settings?

Comment: Nope, but I will now thanks

Comment: what kind of strings ?  (Color, Config, Theme, ... )

Comment: just a piece of text, an email address

Comment: PCLStorage.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For saving a value to local database:

```
string userName = "abc.def";
Application.Current.Properties["username"] = userName;
await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

For retrieving the value in any place of the project:

```
if (Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey("username"))
{
    string UserName = Application.Current.Properties["username"].ToString();
}
```

Use the same key inside [] brackets.

Answer (score 2):

What about the [Properties](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary) Dictionary? 
It's persistent and can be accessed from anywhere!

```
Application.Current.Properties ["email"] = someClass.email;
```

Comment: write answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
Application.Current.Properties
```

only makes the properties, In my case some text, available for the lifetime of the app, if you shut down and re-open they are gone.
I ended up using SimpleIoC, it was quite a bit larger than using 1 or 2 lines so will update my answer soon with the code in case anyone wants / needs it

Answer (score -1):

To store a constant that you need to use in your Xamarin application (Xaml or Code behind) you can use the **Application.Resources** from **App.xaml**

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries/

In your **App.xaml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
 xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
 x:Class="ResourceDictionaryDemo.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
    <clr:String x:Key="MyConstString">My string</clr:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

To access static ressource from XAML :

```
{StaticResource MyConstString}
```

From C# :

```
Application.Current.Resources["resourceName"]
```